# Getting processes invoker

Tags: android, process

Is there any way I can find out what started application? I am working on automation tool and would like to kill all processes started by my test target after the test has finished.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can find out what started application?

The operating system started the application.

> I am working on automation tool and would like to kill all processes started by my test target after the test has finished.

You did not necessarily start any processes. The determination of whether a new process is required, or whether the required app is already running, is handled by the operating system.

However, since your automation tool presumably knows the package(s) being tested, you should be able to use `ActivityManager` to find information about those processes and `PackageManager` to kill them (if they are in the background and you hold the proper permission).